# Replacing values in a dataframe by specification from a vector

Tags: r

Let's say we have a following dataframe named `df`:

```
Country GDP/capita HDI
1       67426      0.92
2       46827      0.92
4       47223      0.89
3       52559      0.94
```

Let's also say we have a *numeric* ***named*** vector `vec` with values `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` and names `USA`, `UK`, `Germany` and `France`.

Given those two objects, what is the fastest way to make the dataframe look like this:

```
Country GDP/capita HDI
USA     67426      0.92
UK      46827      0.92
France  47223      0.89
Germany 52559      0.94
```

(Note that the order of the vector is 1, 2, 3, 4, while the order in the dataframe is 1, 2, 4, 3).

Tidyverse solutions preferred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
vec <- setNames(1:4, c("USA", "UK", "Germany", "France"))

df %>%
 mutate(Country = names(vec)[match(vec, Country)])

  Country GDP_capita  HDI
1     USA      67426 0.92
2      UK      46827 0.92
3  France      47223 0.89
4 Germany      52559 0.94
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
df$Country <- names(vec)[df$Country]
df

#  Country GDP.capita  HDI
#1     USA      67426 0.92
#2      UK      46827 0.92
#3  France      47223 0.89
#4 Germany      52559 0.94
```

---

If you want a `tidyverse` answer you can use :

```
tibble::enframe(vec) %>% dplyr::right_join(df, by = c('value' = 'Country'))
```

Or in base R :

```
merge(stack(vec), df, by.x = 'values', by.y = 'Country')
```